# Where shall I put the assemblies related to tools I use in all my Visual Studio projects?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reference, organization, file-organization

When I develop my web applications in **Visual Studio 2010** I use tools such as **GhostDoc**, **SandCastle**, **AJAX Toolkit**, **Moq**, etc...

I usually use these tools in **all** my projects. When I downloaded the **Moq** tool for instance, I had a zip file with inside a couple of assemblies. Therefore, after unzipping the file, I **added** the relevant assemblies within  the folder (in the file system) of the project I was currently developing, and then I **referenced** the dlls from Visual Studio.

Now the problem, or better organizational drawbacks, with this are 2:

1) I placed the assemblies within a **specific project folder**. That's ugly, since I would like to put the assemblies in one folder **common** to all the projects. Where do you usually put them?

2) Everytime I start a new project I need to reference all the assemblies over again. This, especially with the **Ajax Toolkit** is quite annoying. Is there any way to tell **Visual Studio** to add a set of **predefined** assemblies everytime I create a new project?

Answer (score 2):

For the popular tools you can use [NuGet](http://nuget.org). It will help you manage both the downloading, updating and removal of tools and referencing the appropriate assemblies.

Of the ones you mention, I found the following ones in the official NuGet packages repo:

- Moq
- AjaxControlToolkit